# I have problem with my dx-file uploader is not working inside dx-data-grid(Angular ,T.S.) dev extreme version 21.2.5

Tags: angular, typescript, datagridview, devextreme, angular13

tab.copmonent.html

```
<div id="data-grid-demo">
  <dx-data-grid
    id="gridContainer"
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    keyExpr="ID"
    [showBorders]="true"
  >
    <dxo-paging [enabled]="false"></dxo-paging>
    <dxo-editing
      mode="form"
      [allowUpdating]="true"
      [allowAdding]="true"
      [allowDeleting]="true"
    >
    </dxo-editing>

    <dxi-column dataField="Prefix" caption="Title" [width]="70"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="FirstName"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="LastName"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Position" [width]="170"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="StateID" caption="State" [width]="125">
      <dxo-lookup [dataSource]="states" displayExpr="Name" valueExpr="ID">
      </dxo-lookup>
    </dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="BirthDate" dataType="date"> </dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Notes" [visible]="false">
      <dxo-form-item
        [colSpan]="2"
        editorType="dxTextArea"
        [editorOptions]="{ height: 100 }"
      >
      </dxo-form-item>
    </dxi-column>
 

</dx-data-grid>


   <div id="fileuploader-container"  caption="uploadMode">
    <dx-file-uploader
      selectButtonText="Select File"
      labelText="uploadMode"
      accept="*"
      uploadMode="useForm"
      (onValueChanged)="onFileSelected($event)"
    >
    </dx-file-uploader>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I want to work my file uploader inside dx-data-grid

this is my html code in angular I have problem with my file-uploader it is not working

Comment: Please try for [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: file-uploader is not working inside dx-data-grid form

Comment: it is just showing an empty box inside data grid

Comment: I want my file uploader to work inside dx-grid